# how to manipulate array object and create new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have js array as seen below:

```
var names = [{name:"high",id:1},{name:"high",id:2}, 
{name:"low",id:1},  {name:"low",id:2},{name:"medium",id:1},{name:"medium",id:2}];
```

I need to create another array out of this like this.

```
var newArr=[{name:high,items:[1,2]},{name:low,items:[1,2]},{name:medium,items:[1,2]}];
```

Please suggest me how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org) based solution

```
var obj = {};

_.each(names, function (e) {
    var o = obj[e.name];
    if (o) {
        o.items.push(e.id);
    } else {
        o = {name: e.name, items: [e.id]};
    }
    obj[e.name] = o;
});

var result = _.map(obj, function (e) {return e;});
```

### Pure js

```
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var e = names[i];
    var o = obj[e.name];
    if (o) {
        o.items.push(e.id);
    } else {
        o = {name: e.name, items: [e.id]};
    }
    obj[e.name] = o;
}
var result = [];
for (var k in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        result.push(obj[k]);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks.. I have used the pure js one and it is working perfectly at my end. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple to understand solution without external library.

```
var newArr = []
for ( var i in names ) {
    var exists = findItemInArray(names[i].name,newArr);
    if(exists) {                // Another item with same name was added to newArray
       var items = exists.items.push(names[i].id);    // We add the id to existing item
    } else {                   // No other item with same name was added to newArray
       var newItem = {name:names[i].name, items:names[i].id};
       newArr.push(newItem);
    }
}
```

And I made this function to return the item if it already exists in newArray

```
function findItemInArray(name,array){
    for(var i in array){
       if(array[i].name === name){
           return array[i];
       }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses no external libraries:

```
/**
 * Add the given object to the given set.
 *
 * @param {object} theSet The set to add this object to.
 * @param {object} theObject The object to add to the set.
 *
 * @return {object} theSet, with theObject added to it.
 *
 * @note Assumes that theObject.name should be the key,
 *       while theObject.id should go into the value array.
 * @note This is an Array.prototype.reduce() callback.
 */
function collect(theSet, theObject) {
    if (theSet.hasOwnProperty(theObject.name)) {
        theSet[theObject.name].push(theObject.id);
    } else {
        theSet[theObject.name] = [theObject.id];
    }
    return theSet;
}
var names = [{name:"high",id:5},{name:"high",id:6}, 
             {name:"low",id:1},  {name:"low",id:2},{name:"medium",id:3},{name:"medium",id:4}],
    combinedSet = names.reduce(collect, {}), // This is Step 1
    final = [],
    key;

// This is Step 2
for (key in combinedSet) {
    if (combinedSet.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        final.push(
            {
                "name" : key,
                "items": combinedSet[key]
            }
        );
    }
}
```

The first step is to group the IDs under the object names. I use `Array.prototype.reduce` to do this, with the callback `collect`. The result of that transformation goes into the `combinedSet` variable.

The second step is to take the set we made in Step 1 and turn it into the final array: make objects using the set's keys as the `name` member, and use its values as the `items` member. I can't use `reduce` like I could before, so I go with a simple `for` loop. Note that I wrapped things up with a `hasOwnProperty` check, to guard against the possibility that someone has modified `Object.prototype`; if I didn't do this, then there might be more items in the set that I hadn't put there, and that would introduce bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a grouping function. Try [underscoreJs groupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/53kp4xtr/)

```
var names = [{name:"high",id:1},{name:"high",id:2}, {name:"low",id:1},  {name:"low",id:2},{name:"medium",id:1},{name:"medium",id:2}];

console.debug(_.groupBy(names, 'name'));
// Object {high: Array[2], low: Array[2], medium: Array[2]}, where each item in the nested arrays refers to the original object
```